# Pandas DateTime Apply Method gave Error ''Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt' '

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

data['TS'].dt.second Works , but not in a Apply function.

```
data['TS'] # dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

> 0       2019-06-27 10:13:25
>
> 1       2019-06-27 10:13:08
>
> 2       2019-06-27 10:11:53

```
data['TS'].dt.second
```

> 0        25
>
> 1         8
>
> 2        53

## But

```
from datetime import timedelta
def myTimeFun(tsRow):
    addSec=0 # or some Value
    thisSec=tsRow.dt.second
    return  tsRow + timedelta(seconds=addSec)

data['TS'].apply(myTimeFun)
```

## Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-9a000b768604> in <module>
----> 1 data['TS_Apx30Sec'] = data['TS'].apply(myTimeFun)
      2 data['TS_Apx30Sec']

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py370\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4036             else:
   4037                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4038                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4039 
   4040         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-125-dc9c61ebdaa8> in timeApprx30Sec(tsRow)
      3 def myTimeFun(tsRow):
      4     addSec=0
----> 5     thisSec=tsRow.dt.second

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `shift` function?

Comment: Yes.. I am aware of.. Thats an alternate solution.. Not sure if it is this BugFix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thisSec=tsRow.second #Works & Solved

def myTimeFun(tsRow):
    addSec=0 # or some Value
    thisSec=tsRow.second #thisSec=tsRow.dt.second
    return  tsRow + timedelta(seconds=addSec)
```

Not Sure Why Not  `thisSec=tsRow.dt.second` where as `data['TS'].dt.second` works
If some one has comment about this is appriciable.